# Tools to test WSE enabled SOAP service

Tags: soap, web-services

Is there a tool that can test WSE-Enabled SOAP Web service?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check the outgoing and incoming soap packets.

Use fiddler.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

As soon as you hit the webservice, fiddler will display the outgoing request's xml.

You can also try out firefox's console (disable by default). The console shows all the request/response details.

Fiddler will get the job done for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the WSE element, but my first port of call for testing SOAP Web Services is [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org)

A brilliant tool for calling services and inspecting the results with minimal effort - even before you start to look at its in depth capabilities (which are considerable) and far easier than playing with proxies in the first instance.

Comment: I tried SoapUI, but it didn't work, and gave me error message
I didn't check what those error messages, and I assumed they won't work because WSE is Microsoft specific

Comment: More importantly, WSE is obsolete, and should not be used for new development.